# Registering with Django not working

Tags: python, django

I have to create a website for a project and I encountered a problem with registering a simple user with Django : It seems that the data from the register form are not saved in the database.

It would be nice if someone knew what I did wrong (I am a beginner with Django) because I can't seem to find where the problem is from.

Here are my files :

**models.py** :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Utilisateur(models.Model):
   pseudo = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   prenom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   ACCOUNT_CHOICES = (
       ("U", "Utilisateur"),
       ("H", "Historien"),
       ("F", "Famille"),
   )
   compte = models.CharField(
       max_length=1,
       choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES,
       default="U"
   )
   dateNaissance = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   SEXE_CHOICES = (
       ("M", "Masculin"),
       ("F", "Féminin"),
   )
   sexe = models.CharField(
       max_length=1,
       choices=SEXE_CHOICES,
       default="?"
   )
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

**views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import (render, render_to_response, redirect)
from .forms import UtilisateurInscriptionForm
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth import (authenticate, login)

def inscription_view(request):
    title = "Inscription"
    form = UtilisateurInscriptionForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        new_user = form.save()
        new_user = Utilisateur(
        pseudo = form.cleaned_data['pseudo'],
        password = form.cleaned_data['password'],
        compte = form.cleaned_data['compte'],
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        )

        new_user.set_password(password)

        #we save the user in the database
        new_user.save()

        #We check is the person is registered
        new_user = authenticate(username=pseudo, password=password)

        if new_user is not None:

            if new_user.is_active:
                login(request, new_user)
                return redirect("/")

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "title": title
    }
    return render(request, "inscription.html", context)
```

**forms.py** :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Utilisateur

class UtilisateurInscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
   password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label='Mot de passe')
   email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Email (Confirmation)')
   password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)), label='Mot de Passe (Confirmation)')

class Meta:
    model = Utilisateur
    fields = [
        'pseudo',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        'email',
        'email2',
        'compte',
        ]

def clean_email(self):
    print(self.cleaned_data)
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
    if email != email2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email must match !")
    return email
```

I searched for a long time in order to find what could be wrong but I found nothing useful.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `form.save()` will already save the model for you. Why are you attempting to save it again? Also, you should be receiving an `IntegrityError` because you have non-nullable fields in the model (`nom`, `prenom`) that are not provided by the form.

Comment: I thought that I needed to specify the link between the data of the form and the parameters of my model. Guess I was wrong. Also I don't have the 'IntegrityError' appearing on the console, could it be the reason behind the dysfunction ?